# Retrieving the args given to StopIteration in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, generator

In python generators can return a final value that gets passed into the `StopIteration` exception:

```
def gen():
    yield 3
    yield 1
    return 2

> g = gen()
> next(g)
3
> next(g)
1
> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last): ...
    next(g)
StopIteration: 2
> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last): ...
    next(g)
StopIteration
```

Is there any way to access the value passed into the StopIteration raised in a for loop? something like:

```
> result = 0
> for x in gen():
    result += x
else catch StopIteration as y:
    result /= y.args[0]
> result
2
```

Comment: why not just yield that value, then return nothing?

Comment: The "`return` in a generator" feature is primarily useful for implementing coroutines, rather than for being mixed with actual iteration. Is there a particular reason you want use this approach for a generator that's actually functioning as an iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; `for` loops swallow `StopIteration` exceptions. If you care about the details of the `StopIteration` exception, you'd need to implement the iteration yourself.

That said, there's probably a better way to do whatever you're trying to do.